"It could mean she..." (Subject + Modal Verb + Mean...) Can vs Could
Context: An assessment of someone's observed behavior is being made.
Am I able to use both 'can' and 'could' in this example below:

It could mean she doesn't want anything.
It can mean she doesn't want anything.

If I am able to use both, then I wonder what the difference in meaning is. Could someone help to clarify this for me?

It would be helpful to know the context. What question is that statement the answer to?

Thank you for your suggestion, Kate Bunting. I have added the context.

Could is less sure than can.

OK. In the context of interpreting someone's behaviour, I would interpret It could mean X  as a suggestion of the likely meaning of her behaviour, and  It can mean X as a statement about what such behaviour often means. See this related question. (I agree with 'gotube's answer.)

This question is similar to: Difference between 'can' and 'could'. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There is no way to know the difference in vitro.  The meaning would be dependent on the context in situ, on such things as whether the speaker is defending an explanation they have offered, or acknowledging that someone else's explanation is possible or even probable, or considering various possible explanations and ruling some in, some out.  And even once the context is known, since many speakers would never say "it can explain it", but would always "could" there, you couldn't judge from their choice anything about their degree of certainty. Or even with a speaker who does use both can and could in such contexts, the speaker might  intone could emphatically, or tentatively, and move the needle dramatically on the certainty...uncertainty scale merely with their tone of voice.
The words surrounding that utterance could also change its meaning.

I suppose that could explain it.
Goodness gracious, that could explain it!


There is not much difference in using "can" or could and it is often used interchangeably like in this case.
The primary distinction between "can" and "could" in this context is the degree of certainty or confidence in the interpretation. "Can" suggests a little bit greater confidence or directness than "could"
